# It was ten-seven by the depot clock

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The stained glass of the L&N Depot smoldered like an exhausted
>   butterfly, and at the middle of the viaduct they paused to inhale the
>   burst of smoke from a switch engine which passed under; Rufus, lifted,
>   the cinders stinging his face, was grateful no longer to feel fear at
>   this suspension over the tracks and the powerful locomotives. Far down
>   the yard, a red light flicked to green; a moment later, they heard the
>   thrilling click. It was **ten-seven** by the depot clock. They went
>   on, more idly than before.

*A Death in the Family* by James Agee

Does this mean '**ten to seven**'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ten-seven is 10:07, in other words seven minutes past ten.